# Which type of search would be suitable? (Graph Traversal)

Tags: java, graph, traversal, path-finding

So, you have the following graph that has an Entrance, exit and an arbitrary number of nodes.

[image]

Your task is to get from the entrance to the exit with a resource level of more than 0. When you enter the "maze" you have a resource level of 0, when you land on one of the nodes you must modify your resource level by the amount show in brackets. You must reach the exit node with a resource level of more than 
0.

As you can see the resource count can be either increased or decreased.

What algorithms would be suitable for finding the quickest route through the graph with the prior requirements?

Programming Language - Java

Comment: "Your task is to get from the entrance to the exit in the lowest amount of moves possible" So, those positive and negative weights are not considered at all?

Comment: Well, you must arrive with a resource level of more than 0 (Updated post to include this info)

Comment: Take a look at Dijkstra(http://et.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra_algoritm). You should be able to use same idea.

Comment: Is it possible to us Dijkstras when you have both positive and negative costs?

Comment: No, but you should be able to use it's logic and do some modifications. You still look for the best way from A to B, but you now need to consider, that you look best sum that's >= 0.

Comment: Hmm ok. That might do it, thanks!

Comment: Dijkstra's is actually a 'specialization' of Bellman-Ford (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) for graphs with only positive weights. Bellman-Ford's handles negative weights as well.

Comment: I think you can even just use BFS, as you are not looking for the path with lowest cost but for the path with fewest edges. Just check whether the total cost is >0 before "accepting" a path. Might be different, though, if the path can have loops...

Comment: @DennisW Thats what I thought

Comment: @tobias_k I think you're right. Total cost is a pruning condition.